# Users making their own graphs in Unity--is this possible?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm currently building an educational app, and I'm a complete beginner at Unity so I just wanted to know if what I want to do is possible, and if so, where to even begin.

I want to allow users to graph their own data in unity--as in, they input a number, and that point is created and displayed on a graph. They would only need to do this for about 3 points.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely possible
I would create the graph first create the x axis y axis using the 3d objects

create a cube for the unit - the markings on the graph 
then create a script that creates the cube length and position to where the user wants it to be.
You'll need a script to recieve input from the user too and link that to the units to be created and positioned

Good luck
I am also a newbie on unity but anything is possible with unity